# When is the image of the adjoint representation of a real algebraic group Zariski closed?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, real-algebraic-geometry, linear-groups

Let $\operatorname{Ad}:\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R}))$ be the adjoint representation (i.e. $\operatorname{Ad}(g)X=gXg^{-1}$) of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Then is the image of $\operatorname{Ad}$ a Zariski closed subgroup?

In general, are the any sufficient conditions (e.g. semisimplicity, lack of compact factors) for the image of the adjoint representation of a **real** algebraic group to be Zariski closed?

Comment: No, at least for $n=2$. The image will be the identity component of the group of $\mathbb{R}$-points of a group isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$, hence not Zariski closed.

Comment: I think that *compactness* of $G(\mathbb{R})$ is a sufficient condition  for the image of the adjoint representation of a real algebraic group  to be Zariski closed. Indeed, then the image is compact, hence Zariski closed, see Onishchik and Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups, Section 3.4.4, Theorem 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group over the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.
By "connected" I mean "connected over $\mathbb{C}$".
Let $G(\mathbb{R})$ denote the group of $\mathbb{R}$-points of $G$.
It does not have to be connected.
Let $\Gamma\subset G(\mathbb{R})$ be a subgroup of finite index in $G(\mathbb{R})$,
then its Zariski closure is $G(\mathbb{R})$ (because $G$ is connected).
Thus $\Gamma$ is Zariski closed in $G(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $\Gamma=G(\mathbb{R})$.

Denote by $G^{\mathrm{ad}}$ the image (over $\mathbb{C}$) of the adjoint representation
$$ \mathrm{Ad}\colon G\to \mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Lie}\, G),$$
this group is defined over $\mathbb{R}$.
The image $\mathrm{Ad}(G(\mathbb{R}))$ is a subgroup of finite index in $G^{\mathrm{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$.
We conclude that $\mathrm{Ad}(G(\mathbb{R}))$ is Zariski closed in $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Lie}\, G)$
if and only if $\mathrm{Ad}(G(\mathbb{R}))=G^{\mathrm{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now assume that $G$ is simply connected (over $\mathbb{C}$).
Then $G(\mathbb{R})$ is connected, see Onishchik and Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups, 5.2.1, Thm. 3.
It follows that $\mathrm{Ad}(G(\mathbb{R}))$ is connected, hence it is the identity component of $G^{\mathrm{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$.
Thus $\mathrm{Ad}(G(\mathbb{R}))$ is Zariski closed if and only if $G^{\mathrm{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$ is connected.

Now assume that $G=\mathrm{SL}_n$ (then $G$ is simply connected).  In this case  $G^{\mathrm{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$ has one connected component when $n$ is odd,
and it has two connected components when $n$ is even, see, e.g.,  [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7917), Section 9.3.
Thus $\mathrm{Ad}(\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R}))$ is Zariski closed if and only if $n$ is *odd*.
In particular, in $n=2$, then $\mathrm{Ad}(\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R}))$ is *not* Zariski closed.

Concerning a sufficient condition, it suffices to assume that $G$ is compact (i.e., $G(\mathbb{R})$ is compact), see my second comment to the question.